# I hard is error when I added image_gallery_saver to my flutter project

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, iso

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_gallery_saver:compileDebugKotlin'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_gallery_saver:debugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform artifact 'kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Winchester.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.72\8032138f12c0180bc4e51fe139d4c52b46db6109\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar.
> Cannot parse result path string: